# GWT Fresh Installation not working

Tags: gwt, netbeans, installation

I just did a fresh installation of GWT(Google Web Toolkit) using Netbeans and GWT4NB plugin. I'm also using Glassfish server 3.1. After everything was done I started my server, re-started Netbeans and created a new GWT project like one normally would.

The packages and files gets automatically created like it normally should like the default "Hello, GWT!" and button .java file. I cleaned and built the project and then deployed it to the server.

When I run the project my browser opens with just a blank screen, without displaying the "Hello, GWT!!" message.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a GWT Project in NetBeans with Sample Code and run it. For me this works fine.

I am using GWT4NB version org-netbeans-modules-gwt4nb-2.10.4